# Make app installable from both GitHub & NPM

Tags: node.js, git, npm

`require('./module')` VS `require('module')`

I want my app be installable from both sources GitHub and NPM. I am struggling with `require` directives and folder structures. NPM installs modules in `node_modules` but git would clone into newly created directory inside the working directory and I have to require with `./mymodule` syntax.

I have about 10 modules used by my app, each of them has it's own repository.

How to solve this problem? How to organize folders on the development machine? How to organize repositories?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to clone your repositories in the `node_modules` folder!

If you want to automatically add your repos via `npm install`, you can add your them to your depencies in your `package.json` as specified on the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies):

```
"dependencies" : {
    "project": "git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish"
}
```

And if you want to include [GitHub projects](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls), you'll just have to refer to GitHub urls as just `"foo": "user/foo-project"`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "visionmedia/express",
    "mocha": "visionmedia/mocha#4727d357ea"
}
```